# remove duplicate based on position

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have two lists like below in C#.

```
List 1 = [{Item="A",position =1},{Item="B",position =2},{Item="A",position =3}]
List 2 = [{Item="AA",position =1},{Item="BB",position =2},{Item="AC",position =3}]
```

Now i want to remove duplicate values in the List 1 and that position should be removed in the List 2.

Example o/p

```
   List 1 = [{Item="A",position =1},{Item="B",position =2}]
    List 2 = [{Item="AA",position =1},{Item="BB",position =2}]
```

Can any one help me. Thanks.

Comment: Please share what you tried and why that didn't work.

Comment: Could you also add a second output example since I am not really sure what your trying to accomplish...

Comment: Could you please clarify what you question is and why you've picked the answer? I can't understand what the question and answer means so, as it stands, this question and answer have very little value for the SO community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<string> lst1 = new List<string> { "A", "B", "A" };
List<string> lst2 = new List<string> { "AA", "BB", "AC" };

HashSet<string> seen = new HashSet<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < lst1.Count; i++) {
    if (!seen.Add(lst1[i])) {
        lst1.RemoveAt(i);
        lst2.RemoveAt(i);
        i--;
    }
}
```

I used a [HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) to "save" the "already seen" elements of `lst1` and then simply cycle the `lst1` and remove the duplicate elements. [HashSet.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?) returns `true` if the `HashSet` doesn't already have an element, `false` if it already has it.

It isn't exactly clear what you want/what you have, but here there is the solution for another possible use case:

```
public class MyObject {
    public string Item;
    public int Position;
}

List<MyObject> lst1 = new List<MyObject> { 
    new MyObject { Item = "A", Position = 1 },
    new MyObject { Item = "B", Position = 2 },
    new MyObject { Item = "A", Position = 3 },
};

List<MyObject> lst2 = new List<MyObject> { 
    new MyObject { Item = "AA", Position = 1 },
    new MyObject { Item = "BB", Position = 2 },
    new MyObject { Item = "AC", Position = 3 },
};


HashSet<string> seen = new HashSet<string>();
HashSet<int> toBeDeleted = new HashSet<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < lst1.Count; i++) {
    if (!seen.Add(lst1[i].Item)) {
        toBeDeleted.Add(lst1[i].Position);
        lst1.RemoveAt(i);
        i--;
    }
}

if (toBeDeleted.Count > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lst2.Count; i++) {
        if (toBeDeleted.Contains(lst2[i].Position)) {
            lst2.RemoveAt(i);
            i--;
        }
    }

    // or equivalent and shorter, without the for cycle
    //lst2.RemoveAll(x => toBeDeleted.Contains(x.Position));
}
```

In this case in a first pass on `lst1` we remove the duplicate items (as seen in the first example) and "save" the `Position`s that need to be deleted in the `HashSet<int> tobedeleted` and then we do a second pass on `lst2` to remove the elements that need deleting.

Comment: The question isn't clear, but as the stored objects hold a `position` value, I would assume that this is the position the OP is referring to.

Comment: Hi @X.L.Ant the position value is auto incremental one

Comment: @X.L.Ant I read it as the index of the element. I too was unsure if the element of the `List` was a complex object `Item + Position` or not.

Answer (score 1):

Much not clear what you want do, but I try with this:

```
var filteredList1 = list1.GroupBy(x => x.Item).Select(g => g.First()).ToList(); 
var removeElements = list2.Where(f => !filteredList1.Any(t => t.Position == f.Position)).ToList();  
removeElements.ForEach(x => list2.Remove(x));
```